# Все возможные символы в регулярном выражении

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая регулярка: `'\.\:\-_ a-z0-9а-яА-Я()""-,.!&';`

Тут есть набор почти всех символов. Как сделать что бы все символы были доступны?

Comment: http://www.rubular.com/ можно использовать символ '...' вместо '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9а-яА-Я()""-,.!&'

Comment: Что там про `ё`? И ещё `A-Z` потерялись. И в каком смысле все? Зачем тогда регулярка, если всё можно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Регулярка

```
/./
```

соответствует любому 1 символу кроме перевода строки `\n`.

Для UTF-8 так

```
/./u
```

> Вне символьного класса точка соответствует любому (в том числе и непечатному, бинарному) символу, кроме символа перевода строки '\n' (в обычном режиме). В случае, если используется модификатор PCRE_DOTALL, точка соответствует также символу перевода строки. Обработка метасимвола "точка", никак не связана с метасимволами начала и конца строки, единственное, что у них общего - так это специальное отношение к символу перевода строки. Внутри символьного класса точка не имеет специального значения.

Если нужны только не пробельные символы, то нужно использовать символьный класс `\S`

```
/\S/
```

или

```
/\S/u
```

для UTF-8.

Источники [1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9B.D1.8E.D0.B1.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.BB) [2](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.dot.php)

**UPD**
Если вы используете Codeigniter, то для разрешения всех не пробельных символов + пробела можно использовать такое правило:

```
var $product_name_rules = '\S ';
```

но при таком условии в названии вполне можно ввести js (**если там дальше фильтрация при выводе названия, я не в курсе**).
Можно попробовать использовать правило на основе отрицания

```
var $product_name_rules = '^\x00-\x1F<>';
```

т.е. запрещаем управляющие символы с кодами от `0` до `x1F` и скобки `<` и `>`.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте оператор `.` (точка). Точка соответствует любому символу кроме перевода строки. Обратите внимание на то, что если поместить этот оператор в квадратные скобки (например, `/[a-z.]/`), то он будет обозначать точку, а не "любой символ".

Несколько примеров с подробностями:

- `/./` соответствует любому **одному** символу кроме перевода строки, например, `a`, `b`, `$`, `1`, но не соответствует множеству символов: `abc`.
- Чтобы пример выше сработал, добавьте к точке оператор квантификации (квантификатор), например, `+`: `/.+/`. Теперь это регулярное выражение будет соответствовать **одному или более** любых символов.
- Регулярное выражение `/[a-z-.]+/` будет соответствовать строке, содержащей как минимум один из следующих символов: латинскую букву от a до z в нижнем регистре, дефис и точку. Обратите внимание на то, что точка тут обозначает саму себя, т.к. в квадратные скобки нет смысла помещать оператор, обозначающий совершенно любой символ, именно поэтому в данном контексте этот оператор начинает обозначать точку.

Comment: Почему то не работает, у меня при добавлении в корзину провряет регулярку, если проходит название товара то добавляет товар в корзину. Было так var $product_name_rules    = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9а-яА-Я()""-,.!&'; а сделал вот так var $product_name_rules    = '/.+/';  и не работает)))

Comment: Ни это `var $product_name_rules = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9а-яА-Я()""-,.!&';`, ни это `var $product_name_rules = '/.+/';` не являются регулярными выражениями. Вы что там за систему используете для фильтрации товаров?

Answer (score 1):

Универсальным способом выбрать ВСЕ символы являются следующий: `/[\s\S]/`.
Все символы будут выбраны, поскольку в наборе используется следующий подход:

`\s` - выберет все пробельные символы
`\S` - выберет все символы, кроме пробельных

Соответственно, набор `[\s\S]` содержит все возможные символы.